# Check cron syntax to execute now

Tags: bash, parsing, cron

I do heavy automation on servers.
Biggest problem is the time-based execution of automation things.

The idea is to use a cron-syntax-style to time the executions.
So I need a way to check if a command that is combined to a cron syntax string can be executed now.

Things like:

```
./parser.sh 0 0 * * *
```

will only return OK on Midnight not on all the other minutes of a day.

Also

```
./parser.sh */10 0,1,2,3,4-22/4 * * *
```

and all combinations possible in cron syntax needs to work.

There will be several executions per day, every execution has different syntax.

Is there any kind of stuff that can do this?

It is not possible to actually create cronjobs for this.

Only can use Bash, maybe static compiled binaries, no Python nor higher languages.

Already tried https://github.com/morganhk/BashCronParse but this cannot interpret things like 1,2,3,4,5... only single numbers and */n, neither combinations.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at your cron's source code.

Comment: Well, that's a problem... I am not a programmer, just a scripting sysadmin.

Comment: Do you want a conditional cron, like if the output os parser.sh is OK, then run parser.sh with another schedule? Or do you want several schedules for the same script?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot get your question clearly. But, if you are trying to run parser.sh every minute of the day.

Use this

`./parser.sh * * * * *`

Comment: I do not have any parser.sh yet. I need something like that, maybe also cron itself is possible?

Comment: Whatever command that you want to execute can be written in some sh file and execute that sh file in the cron job

Comment: The automation itself runs every minute by cron, that it needs to check which of the configured jobs it needs to run now. This check is the problem here. I cannot create a crontab entry for every possible job manually.

Comment: sounds like you are talking about a scheduling system. There are numerous comercial products, but sounds like you can't afford them. Then your robust option is to store records in a local database that store current status and dependencies. I have done such a thing, and was glad that I had a real database to do it with. Any of the free DBs would be perfectly fine, so see if one is installed already. Good luck.

Comment: I realized that this is impossible for me to realize. So I think I will do some kind of tool that creates real crontab entries to let the real cron do the job...